# sinatra 'namespace' not working when trying modular way

Tags: ruby, sinatra

Here is my code , but 'namespace' is not taking , If I write without namespace it is working , also it will work with 'namespace' if I remove class declaration and execute directly .

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/namespace'

     class MyApp < Sinatra::Base
        namespace "/v1" do
          get "/" do
          "Hello World!"
          end  
        end
      end
```

**1: from test1.rb:4:in `<main>'
test1.rb:5:in`': undefined method `namespace' for MyApp:Class (NoMethodError)**

Comment: In your class, try registering it: `register Sinatra::Namespace`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the [Sinatra documentation](http://sinatrarb.com/contrib/namespace) you need to register the extension:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/namespace'

class MyApp < Sinatra::Base
    register Sinatra::Namespace

    namespace "/v1" do
        get "/" do
            "Hello World!"
        end  
    end
end
```